# How to replace text submit button in custom tinymce window?

Tags: jquery, button, tinymce, submit

I am tring to change with jQuery the submit text button, inside a tinymce window, using

```
jQuery('#process').html('generating shortcode...');
```

It works but problem is that the button does not maintain its css properties and new text is added visually wrong.

You can reproduce it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixolo/3aggLvba/

What is wrong?
Thanks